# Concatenate Two Tensors in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

How do I pad a tensor of shape `[71 32 1]` with zero vectors to make it `[100 32 1]`?

> RuntimeError: invalid argument 0: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Got 32 and 71 in dimension 0 at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMath.cu:87

I tried by concatenating a padding vector of zeros of shape `[29 32 1]`. I get the error above. I try with a padding vector of zeros of shape `[29 32 1]`, I still get an error.

Answer (score 20):

In order to help you better, you need to post the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that caused the error, without it we are just guessing here...

Guessing from the error message you got:

#### 1.

> ```
> Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2
> ```

pytorch tries to concat along the 2nd dimension, whereas you try to concat along the first.

#### 2.

> ```
> Got 32 and 71 in dimension 0
> ```

It seems like the dimensions of the tensor you want to concat are not as you expect, you have one with size `(72, ...)` while the other is `(32, ...)`.
You need to check this as well.

#### Working code

Here's an example of concat

```
import torch

x = torch.rand((71, 32, 1))
# x.shape = torch.Size([71, 32, 1])
px = torch.cat((torch.zeros(29, 32, 1, dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device), x), dim=0)
# px.shape = torch.Size([100, 32, 1])
```

Alternatively, you can use [`functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.pad):

```
from torch.nn import functional as F

px = F.pad(x, (0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 0))
```

Comment: Here is the function signature of `torch.cat()`: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html#torch.cat